# How do Biblical Unitarians understand the earthly and heavenly tabernacles through the lens of "notional existence"?

Tags: exodus, hebrews, biblical-unitarian, tabernacle

Exodus 25:9 says:

> According to all that I shew thee, after the pattern of the tabernacle, and the pattern of all the instruments thereof, even so shall ye make it.

Exodus 25:40 says:

> And look that thou make them after their pattern, which was shewed thee in the mount.

And Hebrews 8:5 says:

> Who serve unto the example and shadow of heavenly things, as Moses was admonished of God when he was about to make the tabernacle: for, See, saith he, that thou make all things according to the pattern shewed to thee in the mount.

Hebrews 9 seems to indicate that Jesus entered into an real heavenly temple and purified the items there with his own blood.  In other words, the actually physical items on earth were only shadows and patterns of the non-physical entities in the heavens.  In this case the non-physical is presented as more "real" than the physical.

How does this affect the Biblical Unitarian theory of "notional" vs. "actual" existence?

related: [Was the Tabernacle and its furnishings a copy of things in Heaven?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20283/was-the-tabernacle-and-its-furnishings-a-copy-of-things-in-heaven)

Comment: Are you suggesting the spiritual is NOT more real than the physical?

Comment: @steveowen nope